# LocalDate in an stable class in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, java-time, kotlinx-datetime

I want to have a field in a data class that is type of `java.time.LocalDate` or `kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime`. This class will be consumed in a composable method.

But in metric report this class is unstable because of this field unstability.

How can I have an stable LocalDateTime class?

Comment: What are you using to generate that warning? `LocalDateTime` is immutable already. Perhaps your tool just doesn't know about it.

Comment: @Jorn I'm using https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability/diagnose#compose-compiler for getting the report. I don't think so.

Comment: You don't think what? That LocalDateTime is immutable? It really is.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a data class which you promise to the platform that using `@Immutable`, you will always make a new copy of the data when you pass it.

for example:

```
@Immutable
data class ImmutableLocalDateTime(
    val ldt: LocalDateTime
)
```

Then you can use it on your data class and it is stable now for example:

```
data class StateClass(
    val randomVar: String,
    val dateTime: ImmutableLocalDateTime
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Comment: *why* though? `LocalDateTime` itself is already immutable.

Comment: I suppose compose takes as granted immutable classes like: Int,String, Boolean - the others should be marked explicitly with `@Stable` or `@Immutable`

Comment: I doubt it's a Compose problem TBH. Sounds more like a missing feature in whatever generates the OP's "metric report"

Comment: @F.Mysir Thanks. I upvoted it. But I didn't want to use a wrapper class for anything :(